# In mongoose, how to find records based on value in related collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

In Mongoose, I have two collections, with one referencing the other. Is it possible to have a find query that selects records based on a value in the other. An example of what I am try to get at (not actual schemas):

```
const CarModelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   brand: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CarBrand' }
});

const CarBrandSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   country: String
});
```

I then want to perform a query of the form, without needing to do two queries:

```
CarModelSchema.find({ 'brand.country': 'GER' });
```

So far I haven't been able to make this work, so I am wondering whether this can be done in Mongo or whether I am approaching it wrong?

Comment: If you want combine data use [$aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible.

I realize you don't have models for your schemas so add them like this:

```
const CarModel = mongoose.model('CarModel', CarModelSchema);
const CarBrand = mongoose.model('CarBrand', CarBrandSchema);
```

Also brands should be defined like this:

```
brand: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CarBrand' }] //added the brackets
```

You can then run a find query to filter by country by doing the following:

```
CarModel.
  find(...).
  populate({
    path: 'brand',
    match: { country: { $eq: 'GER' }},
    // You can even select the field you want using select like below, 
    select: 'name -_id',
    //Even limit the amount of documents returned in the array
    options: { limit: 5 }
  }).
  exec();
```

And that should do it, as long as the ObjectIds saved in `brands` array in the `CarModel` collection are valid or exist.

Comment: This still find all the car match the filter in `find()` ! Also the `brand` field is not an array.

Comment: His schema is incorrect. `brand: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CarBrand' }` should `brand: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CarBrand' }]`. Notice I added the brackets @CuongLeNgoc . I'll update my answer to reflect the change

Comment: But `brand: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CarBrand' }` is correct syntax. Why you change it?

Comment: If you need an array see docs https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html first thing you'll see. You need to store all _ids in an array in order to retrieve the related documents on populate @CuongLeNgoc

Answer (score 1):

Using *match* in your population will do the work.

```
CarModel.find()
  .populate({
     path: 'brand',
     model: CarBrandModel,
     match: { country: { $eq: 'GER' }},
  })
  .exec()
```

Keep in mind you have to define `CarModel` and `CarBrandModel` like this:

```
const CarModel = mongoose.model('CarModel', CarModelSchema)
const CarBrandModel = mongoose.model('CarBrandModel', CarBrandSchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are doing it wrong.

In `CarModelSchema.brand` there is not string saved, there is ObjectId saved, therefore you have to find that ObjectId (the reference).

You can do it manually - first finding the `CarBrandSchema.find({ 'country': 'GER' });` and then use its ObjectId (=`_id`), or you can use https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html to populate your CarModel with the CarBrand object.